# Weblogic replays request exactly after 5 minutes

Tags: java, multithreading, weblogic

we're investigating an issue where a specific web request processing lasts long on our Weblogic 10.3 server. Exactly after 5 minutes the server starts processing the very same request, causing an error in the application logic. This happens even 3 or 4 times. Can you help me which server setting or whatever might cause this?

In the logs we can see these entries:

```
<BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "667" seconds working on the request "weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@2f35bea[
.......
]", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:
Thread-65 "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" <alive, in native, suspended, priority=1, DAEMON> {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: the client software was resending the request in a loop if the connection timed out.